# gitolite hook for specific repository

Tags: hook, gitolite

I don't understand how do I create a post-receive hook for a **specific** repository in gitolite (non-root install)

My bare repository contains a website that should copy the working directory to the docRoot
(`GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/htdocs git checkout -f`) on update

Before gitolite, I would just update the hook for the specific repository.
Gitolite documentation mentions that all hooks should be at `hooks/common` so I don't understand how it works.

What should be the name of hooks, where it should be located and how it's structure should be changed (if it should)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update July 2013: what follows is for gitolite V2 (or 'g2'), which was the version used by the OP at the time (November 2011).

Update August 2013, with the latest gitolite 3.x:
You now have [official specific repo hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18431200/6309):

> it's basically just creating a symlink in `<repo.git>/hooks` pointing to some file inside `$rc{LOCAL_CODE}/hooks/repo-specific` (except the `gitolite-admin` repo)

---

All hooks in `gitolite/hooks/common` are replicated in all repositories managed by Gitolite, as detailed in the [hook propagation documentation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/hook_prop.html).
That means your hook script must take specific action depending on the repo which execute said hook.

You can either use the `$GL_REPO` variable (which gitolite set and pass to all its scripts for any git command it receives).

Or you can use some git configuration registered on the gitolite server, like the [mirroring hook does](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/mirroring.html). See the [`post-receive.mirrorpush` hook](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/fda10c280579d0c49cafd1aba594581859f1dfa5/hooks/common/post-receive.mirrorpush).

The [OP Eyal R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067880/eyal-r) adds in the comments:

> But I still don't understand how it is done (I understand that `$GL_REPO` is used to determine which repo I am updating but I'm missing the practical part).
>   I have created a file called `post-receive.test` with `echo "test"`, put it in `$HOME/gitolite/hooks/common`, ran `gl-setup`, ran push from workstation - nothing happens (no "`test`" output)

To which I replied:

> The hook should appear in the `hook` directory of your repo on the gitolite server as a link, linking back to the `.gitolite/common/hook`. Note that it should be in `$HOME/.gitolite/common/hook`, not `/gitolite`.

The OP confirms the missing dot was the issue.

The process to add an hook is detailed in [Hook propagation in gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/hook_prop.html), and their usage in "[Using Hooks](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/hooks.html)".

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand how it is done (I understand that $GL_REPO is used to determine which repo I am updating but I'm missing the practical part). I created a file called post-receive.test with echo "test" , put it in /gitolite/hooks/common , I ran gl-setup , ran push from workstation - nothing happens (no "test" output)

Comment: When you are publishing your hook in your local `gitolite-admin` repo, and then push that `gitolite-admin` repo to the gitolite server, *then* gitolite propagate all hooks in all repo. Did you set chmod 775 your script?

Comment: What do you mean by "publish a hook"

Comment: Just copy the hook in the `hook/common` directory of your local `gitolite-admin` repo.

Comment: Actually, I just re-read the doc: you need to add hooks directly on the server, not through the local gitolite-admin like it used to be. See http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/hooks.html. Once added, you need to run "`gl-setup`" in order for gitolite to propagate the hook to all repos (through symlinks linking back from the repos to that one hook you just added).

Comment: As I wrote in my first comment - I did that. what should be the file name? maybe that is the problem...

Comment: The hook should appear in the hook directory of your repo on the gitolite server as a link, linking back to the `.gitolite/common/hook`. Note that it should be in `$HOME/.gitolite/common/hook`, not `/gitolite` as you wrote in your first comment.

Comment: Ok , the problem was the missing dot... thank you very much (though it is still weird I need to take care within the script if the current repo will fire the code)

Comment: You are welcome. I have included part of those comments in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC, just want to confirm, it is $HOME/.gitolite/hooks/common or $HOME/.gitolite/common/hook?

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl all links restored ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is a fairly common need for someone using gitolite, and appears to be a little difficult to tie up loose ends when being not a very advanced user (at leas it was for me).

Following stackoverflow's and gitolite's links back and forth can be a little confusing. These are my conclusions and the path I followed to be able to achieve this.

As @VonC mentioned creating repository specific hooks is already possible since [version 3.5.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430522/gitolite-admin-hooks-and-mirroring/18431200#18431200) ([github link](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/62fb31755abb7ad93e17a6fe8880b74eb17086fa))

**Update/Upgrade Gitolite**

The first thing you should do is update your gitolite repo. So **ssh** into your server that is hosting gitolite and move to the location where gitolite is installed (usually `/home/git/gitolite`) as the git user (usually `git`)

Example:

```
$ ssh myusername@devserver.com
$ sudo su - git
$ pwd
/home/git
$ cd gitolite
```

Then we have to [upgrade gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install.html#upgrading). To do so, first we need to update the gitolite repository

```
$ git pull
```

Then we have to repeat the [install command  (make sure you use the same arguments as before)](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install.html#the-actual-install)

```
$ ./install
```

And finally run the setup again.

```
$ gitolite setup
```

If that doesn't work, you probably haven't set up gitolite executable in your `PATH`, so you could do something like this:

$ src/gitolite setup

**Gitolite Settings (The "RC" file)**

This was one of the parts that confused me the most, but it ended up it was pretty straight forward.

The famous "rc" file is located at git's home directory `/home/git/.gitolite.rc`. There make sure you have a variable called `LOCAL_CODE`, you should see something like this on that file, if not, add it.

```
LOCAL_CODE => "$ENV{HOME}/.gitolite/local"
```

And in the "commands an feature to enable" section you should make sure that `repo-specific-hooks` is available, if not, add it.

```
ENABLE => [

    # COMMANDS

        # These are the commands enabled by default
        'help',
        'desc',
        'info',
        ...,
        ...,
        ...,
        'repo-specific-hooks'
        ...,
        ...,
        ...
]
```

[Here is the link to the documentation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cust.html#rsh)

**Writing Repository Specific Hooks**

Finally, in your **local** `gitolite-admin` repository create the following directories `hooks/repo-specific` under the directory you just set in the `LOCAL_CODE` variable, for example:

```
gitolite_admin/local/hooks/repo-specific
```

After that you can actually add your hooks scripts to that location and manage them through the gitolite conf file as [stated in the documentation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cust.html#rsh). Make sure the scripts are executable.

```
repo foo
RW+                       =   @all
option hook.post-receive  =   deploy
```

Again, I hope this helps some of you guys.

Cheers!

Comment: So, `deploy` is the script name. Where should it be placed in `gitolite_admin/local/hooks/repo-specific` directory? What if several repos want to have a script with the same name (say `deploy`), how to distinguish them? I need more examples to understand your explanation

Comment: It's been a while since I haven't set up gitolite again. I'm going to try to answer your question, hope I do.

Yes, your scripts need to be placed under the directory `gitolite_admin/local/hooks/repo-specific`. If you wanted to use different `deploy` scripts per repo, you're going to have to create a deploy script per repo and set that up in a per repo basis. e.g

    repo foo
    RW+     =   @all
    option hook.post-receive = deploy-foo

    repo bar
    RW+     =   @all
    option hook.post-receive = deploy-bar

Comment: So, `deploy-foo`, `deploy-bar`, will have to be in the directory `gitolite_admin/local/hooks/repo-specific`

Comment: I have set local code to: `LOCAL_CODE                =>  "$rc{GL_ADMIN_BASE}/local",` but otherwise this works perfectly for me.

Comment: Your instruction is better then original doc http://gitolite.com/gitolite/non-core/#repo-specific-hooks. After pushing changes in gitolite-admin repo I got warning `repo-specific-hooks: '..../local/hooks/repo-specific' does not exist or is not a directory.` So I created it manually and tried again and I got another error: `repo-specific-hooks: '..../local/hooks/repo-specific/deploy' doesn't exist or is not executable` because I see that created symlink foo.git/hooks/post-receive points to not existing file: ..../local/hooks/multi-hook-driver Any ideas whats wrong?