# gitolite_admin hooks and mirroring

Tags: gitolite

I'm wondering is there a simple way to install hooks for certain repo using gitolite_admin.

Let's imagine i want to have ***post-update*** hook for repo ***awesome*** using **gitolite_admin** repo cloned to my workstation...

```
#conf/gitolite_conf
repo    awesome
        RW+     =   deployer
```

contents of **post-update**:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Post receive-hook => updating Redmine repository"
sudo -u deployer perl -we '`cd /home/deployer/repo/awesome.git && git fetch -q --all`'
```

Comment: The latest commit in Gitolite seems to introduce repo-specifc hook: see [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18431200/6309)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [sitaram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2353097/sitaram)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18436949/6309), the recent (August 29th, 2013) [commit 62fb31755a](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/62fb31755abb7ad93e17a6fe8880b74eb17086fa) formerly introduce repo specific hooks:

> it's basically just creating a symlink in `<repo.git>/hooks` pointing to some file inside `$rc{LOCAL_CODE}/hooks/repo-specific` (except the gitolite-admin repo)

You cannot specific a hook for `gitolite-admin` though.
And you hook is only one of the three following authorized hooks:

- `pre-receive`
- `post-receive`
- `post-update`

That means you can:

- store your repo specific hooks in your `gitolite-admin/hooks/repo-specific/xx`
- declare those your in the `gitolite-admin local` options on the server.

First enable those hooks:

```
ENABLE => [

             # allow repo-specific hooks to be added
             # 'repo-specific-hooks',
```

Then declare the hooks on the server `gitolite-admin` repo:

```
gitolite git-config gitolite-options.hook=reponame hookname scriptname
```

(with a tab or \t between `reponame hookname scriptname`)

---

Original answer:

As mention in the [gitolite man page on hooks](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/non-core/#hooks-and-gitolite)

> if you want to install a hook in only a few specific repositories, do it directly on the server.

(otherwise, you would be managing hooks for *all* git repos [through `gitolite-admin/common/hooks`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12209627/6309))

That being said, you could take advantage of [**`VREF`**](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref/index.html) in gitolite V3.x, which are update hooks: those can be set for some repos and for some user, like any other rule.
You could then:

- make your `VREF` script leave a 'flag' (a file) in the appropriate bare git repo being updated
- make a common '`deploy`' `post-update` hook, which would first look for that flag, and if found, deploy the repo (and remove the flag).

Again:

- a post-update hook managed through `gitolite-admin` can only be common to all git repos (not what you want)
- only VREFs can be associated to repos and users through gitolite.conf

The solution above tries to take those two facts into account to achieve what you are looking for: a `deploy` script running only for certain repos and managed through the `gitolite.conf` config file of the `gitolite-admin` repo.

Answer (score 3):

You could also look at "[repo-specific environment variables](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/dev-notes.html#rsev)"

> **A special form of the option syntax can be used to set repo-specific environment variables that are visible to gitolite triggers and any git hooks you may install**.
>
> For example, let's say you installed a post-update hook that initiates a CI job. By default, of course, this hook will be active for all gitolite-managed repos. However, you only want it to run for some specific repos, say r1, r2, and r4.
>
> To do that, first add this to the `gitolite.conf`:

```
repo r1 r2 r4
    option ENV.CI = 1
```

> This creates an environment variable called GL_OPTION_CI with the value 1, before any trigger or hook is invoked.
>
> Note: option names must start with `ENV.`, followed by a sequence of characters composed of alphas, numbers, and the underscore character.
>
> Now the hook running the CI job can easily decide what to do:

```
# exit if $GL_OPTION_CI is not set
[ -z $GL_OPTION_CI ] && exit

... rest of CI job code as before ...
```

> Of course you can also do the opposite; i.e. decide that the listed repos should not run the CI job but all other repos should:

```
repo @all
    option ENV.CI = 1

repo r1 r2 r4
    option ENV.CI = ""
```

---

That feature is fairly recent (started in [commit 999f9cd39](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/999f9cd39d0d787fc390c6a8ccc17cf84702017f), but in this case, completed in [commit 63865a16](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/63865a16eb06218318f5d7c21faa4878db9b6693) June 2013 for 3.5.2).
But even you don't have that version, there are other ways to do this using option variables, as the last part of that section explains.

> Before this feature was added, you could still do this, by using the `gitolite git-config` command inside the hook code to test for options and configs set for the repo, like:

```
if gitolite git-config -q reponame gitolite-options.option-name
then
    ...
```

And you can use git config variables in the same way.
Or you can use group membership -- see the comments against [function "`in_group`"](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/09e3a3ca477b2569fd70c46fc5493402da30d674/src/lib/Gitolite/Easy.pm#L94-L106) in "[`Easy.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Easy.pm)" for details.

```
# in_group()

# return true if $ENV{GL_USER} is set and is in the given group

# shell equivalent
# if gitolite list-memberships $GL_USER | grep -x $GROUPNAME >/dev/null; then ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are step by step instructions to complement @VonC's answer

[gitolite hook for specific repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322860/gitolite-hook-for-specific-repository/22417905#22417905)